Paying fees with custom asset fails
I have a runtime that allows fee payment in different assets since it implements the pallet_asset_tx_payment pallet.
This works perfectly fine when the transaction is not submitted with the PolkadotJS wallet or Talisman.
For example, I wrote the following script to submit the transaction:
const test = async () => {
    const api = await ApiPromise.create({
        provider: new WsProvider('wss://...'),
        signedExtensions: {
        ChargeAssetTxPayment: {
            extrinsic: {
            tip: 'Compact<Balance>',
            assetId: 'Option<AssetId>',
            },
            payload: {},
        },
        },
    });

  const remarkCall = api.tx.system.remark('0x44');
  await cryptoWaitReady();
  const PHRASE = '...';
  const pair = keyring.addFromUri(PHRASE);

  await submitExtrinsic(pair, remarkCall, { assetId: 1 });
}

async function submitExtrinsic(
  signer: KeyringPair,
  call: SubmittableExtrinsic<'promise'>,
  options: Partial<SignerOptions>
): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const unsub = call.signAndSend(signer, options, ({ status, isError }) => {
      console.log(`Current status is ${status}`);
      if (status.isInBlock) {
        console.log(`Transaction included at blockHash ${status.asInBlock}`);
      } else if (status.isFinalized) {
        console.log(`Transaction finalized at blockHash ${status.asFinalized}`);
        unsub.then();
        return resolve();
      } else if (isError) {
        console.log('Transaction error');
        unsub.then();
        return reject();
      }
    });
  });
}

This transaction is successful. However, when I try to submit the same transaction via a UI where I sign the transaction with Polkadotjs, I get the following error (note that the code is essentially the same, except it is signed with Polkadotjs):
Error: createType(SignerPayload):: Struct: failed on assetId: Option<TAssetConversion>:: Struct: Cannot decode value 1 (typeof number), expected an input object, map or array



Polkadot.js API v12.0.2 includes changes on how the signAndSend method works when used in a workflow with an extension or external signer. This change was done to allow the signer to add the metadataHash to the signing payload (as it is done by Ledger device in their new firmware version). Hence you have to adapt your workflow for the case when the transaction is being signed "externally" as it seems is your case you are reporting here.
Please, check the relevant PR for details on how to adapt your script but it should be as simple as setting the optional withSignedTranscation of the signAndSend method.

I just tried to set the withSignedTransaction and it still doesn't work; I'm receiving the same error. This issue is possibly related to: https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues/5846

after the change, is the error the same regardless of using Talisman or PJS extension in your workflow to sign the tx?

Yes, it is the same. And it is the same error as the one I specified in the question.

I think it is better then to report this in the PJS extension repo. It seems that indeed the extension is assuming a specific type for Option<AssetId> (a XCM multilocation like in Asset Hub runtime) and if a different type is passed then it breaks. That being said, since this is a custom chain workflow, you may need to implement the changes to the extension locally yourself.
